# Determine the joint density of $X+Y$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $ X,Y\colon (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), P) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ be random variables. I want to show that if either $X$ or $Y$ has a density, then $Z:=X+Y$ has a density, too. Denote $P_X(A):=P(X^{-1}(A))$ the distribution of $X$ and likewise for $Y$ and $F_x(x):=P\circ X^{-1}((-\infty, x])$ the distribution function.

*My attempt*:

By standard procedure
\begin{eqnarray}
F_Z(z) &=& P(X+Y\le z) = P(Y\le z-X) = \int_\mathbb{R} P(Y\le z-x)\mathrm{d}P_X(x)=\int_\mathbb{R} F_Y(z-x)\mathrm{d}P_X(x)
\end{eqnarray}

Ok this was simple so far. I can also immediately see, that if **both** distributions have a density then the density of $Z$ is given by convolution of the densities of $X$ and $Y$.

If **only** $Y$ has a density: 
$$F_Z(z)=\int_\mathbb{R}\int_{-\infty}^{z-x}f_Y(y)\mathrm{d}P\,\mathrm{d}P_X(x)$$
If the distribution of $Z$ has a density with respect to another measure $\mu$ must have the form $P_Z(A)=\int_Af\mathrm{d}\mu$. However, I dont' see what the density should be here.

If **only** $X$ has a density:

$$F_Z(z)=\int_\mathbb{R}F_Y(z-x)f_X(x)\mathbb{d}P$$

I am a bit confused of what the density $f_Z(z)$ is.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ has a density $f_X$ then $g(x)=\int f_X(x-y)dP_Y(y)$ defines a density function and it is the density function of $X+Y$. The only tool you requite for proving this is Fubini's Theorem.

Comment: Please elaborate on that, I cannot see why this would hold true. Not sure how Fubini comes into place here. How did you transform $F_Y(z-x)$?